# Characteristic of residue class field

Tags: number-theory, valuation-theory

I‘m currently reading Neukirchs „algebraic number theory“. In Chapter II he stated the following

> **9.12 Proposition** The ramification group $R_\omega$ is the unique p-Sylow subgroup of the
>   inertia group $I_\omega.$

We assume here, that L over K is Galois, where K admits a non-Archimedean valuation $v$ and L some extension $\omega$ of this $v$. My question is simple: Where does p come from? The proof says, that p is the characteristic of the residue class field of L. But does this field always have positive characteristic?

Best regards
Roland

Comment: If $K$ is a number field? Yes.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately K is an arbitrary valued field. So do I just have to add „in case the residue class field characteristic is of positive characteristic p the following proposition holds:“?

Comment: If the residue characteristic is 0, then the ramification field is $L$.